# Giving two meanings to an element for assistive technologies using "role"

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am having an issue with understanding ARIA roles for my use case. I have created a table using div elements in the following way:

```
<div role="table" class="table">
    <div role="rowgroup" class="tbody">
        <div role="row" class="tr">
            <button class="td" role="cell">Clickable cell</button>
            <a class="td" role="cell" href="#">Link cell</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I enable VoiceOver on macOS (I only have this tool for testing for now) and start to navigate using keyboard. When I get to the texts "Clickable cell" and "Link cell," I keep hearing the contents of the cell, followed by "You are currently on a text element, inside of a cell." Is there a way to tell make the screen reader tell the user that it is a link and a cell?

I tried to use multiple roles `role="link cell"` but nothing changed. It kept telling me the same thing.

EDIT: Even removing the role from "div" altogether does not help with accessibility, VoiceOver app still thinks that it is a cell. Would it be more logical to add a screen reader only text that says "All the cells are clickable / links"?

Comment: From your code I don't see any necessity of using ARIA roles instead of HTML. Did you clean up your code? You should always prefer semantic HTML to a DIV soup.

Comment: Regarding this, did you try to put the real route in the `href`? Maybe VoiceOver doesn't consider # links as real links?

Comment: @Andy I will test it out, I have links such as "#some-link1" and they are also not accepted as links but I will check it with real links to see if there is a difference. Regarding using DIVS, I got fed up from trying to set a button or anchor height to the height of the cell using CSS (if one cell has content in two lines, the heights do not work in any browser); so, I ended up using DIVS and setting table cells as links. Functionally, they work as I want them to. My only concern is making them accessible.

Comment: @Andy I know I am going a bit off topic here but here is the issue that I am talking about (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moYOzv). The second column has larger text; so, the cells in first col will never stretch to cell's size. I want the cell to be "clickable" and every approach that I tried failed me. So, I ended up using divs and other tags to define rows and cols using CSS and ARIA roles.

Answer (score 3):

The [First rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1) is not to use ARIA.  That is, use a real <table>.  That always needs to be stated any time you think you need to use ARIA attributes or roles.  Decide if there's a native HTML way to do what you want.

The [Second rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#secondrule) is don't change native semantics.  In other words,

```
<button class="td" role="cell">Clickable cell</button>
```

is a no no.  You just removed all the "buttoness" of the button so a screen reader will no longer know that "Clickable cell" is a button.  Instead, it thinks it's a <td> (role="cell").

You should add another <div> and give it a `role="cell"` and then embed your button and link inside it.

```
<div role="table" class="table">
  <div role="rowgroup" class="tbody">
    <div role="row" class="tr">
      <div role="cell">
        <button class="td" role="cell">Clickable cell</button>
        <a class="td" role="cell" href="#">Link cell</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That would be the same as

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="td" role="cell">Clickable cell</button>
        <a class="td" role="cell" href="#">Link cell</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please check my comment above on why this approach did not work for me. I can't resize cell contents to fit the cell for some reason. So, I ended up using aria roles and css to imitate a table that works with other tags.

Comment: @gasim slugolicios suggested also the first block, which is still using your divs but separating the roles button and cell. did you try that?

Comment: I have tried this with normal tables but I will try it out with divs. Thanks!